# Make text fade in and stay visible until mouse leaves the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm tying to make text `fadeIn` and stay **visible** while the **mouse pointer** is in the **container** and only when the **mouse pointer leaves** the designated area, only then must the text `fadeOut` but for some reason its not working, the text will `fadeOut` even when the mouse is inside the container.

I'm using Jquery lib 1.10.1 as well as Jquery ui 1.11.0

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="hold">
    <div class="conti">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-fade"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hold{
    width: 142px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:10px;
}
.conti{
    width: 30px;
}
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid green;
}
.text-fade{
    display: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.hold').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.arrow-right').effect("bounce", { direction:'right', times:3 }, 700);
    $('.text-fade').text("this is a test text").fadeIn(1000).css('display',"block");
});
$('.hold').mouseout(function () {
    $('.text-fade').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

This is the link to my [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w8F47/2/)

Comment: looks like your fiddle points to a different problem? `$(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'right', times:1 }, 700);`

Comment: seems like your fiddle does not correspendent to your code above? What is you current code?

Comment: see when the mouse hovers over the text it fades out i kinda fixed the container problem but i only want the text to fade out when the mouse is out the actual container

Comment: Why not use pure CSS3 like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w8F47/28/)?

Comment: @VinceCgto reason why I'm not using pure CSS because of browser compatibility issues where jquery tends to remove that issue completely and its always a safer option when dealing with clients that's super old school and stuck in the stone ages lol

Comment: Browser support is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) actually. It works in quite a lot of browser versions...except 'stone age' IE9 or lower of course. Those darned clients ;)

Comment: lol now see there these clients are using browser we all tend to hate "IE" and the plugin must be coded for version 9 and lower :( but i whack that like a BOSS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mouseout is triggered by children, use mouseleave instead

```
$('.hold').mouseenter(function () {
    // var d = $('.arrow-right');
    // d.effect("bounce", { direction:'right', times:3 }, 700);
    $('.text-fade').text("this is a test text").fadeIn(1000);
});
$('.hold').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.text-fade').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

[JS fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/w8F47/26/)

Comment: woooooohhhhh nice one man...ON THE MONEY:D shot for that you the shizz nice one:)

Comment: just a heads up the updated fiddle some code was commented out dont do that man when updating it please:) cuz i needed all that code but shot again

Comment: Might wanna do this instead `$('.text-fade').stop().fadeOut(1000)`

Comment: @VinceCgto yeah to be extra safe i think ill add it to my code shot man +1 for your effort as well('thumbs up')

Answer (score 0):

Put the text directly into ".text-fade" and give some transition to the ".text-fader" class. Then change the text color via JS.

Here's the code for changing from #FFFFFF to #000000 and back again:

```
$('.hold').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.arrow-right').effect("bounce", { direction:'right', times:3 }, 700);
    $('.text-fade').css('color', '#000000');
});
$('.hold').mouseout(function () {
    $('.text-fade').css('color', '#FFFFFF');
});
```

Comment: the color of the text cant change because its going to be put as a call to action on a slider see, so i need the text only to fade out once the mouse leaves the container where the slider is positioned, so sorry bro your answer aint going to work but shot for the answer bro

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong functions, its mouseenter() and mouseleave()

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w8F47/24/)

your javascript

```
$('.hold').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.text-fade').text("this is a test text");
    $('.text-fade').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.text-fade').show();
});
$('.hold').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.text-fade').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

also that bounce function you had seems to cause some problems that I could not find out why so I removed it

Comment: no no dude i needed the bounce function there, still got it working flawless ;) with the bounce function this working version is the correct one http://jsfiddle.net/w8F47/26/